# Searching for Metasyntax name/spec

Tags: parsing, syntax, bnf

I'm currently searching for the name and spec for the metasyntax used in this article to describe the proposed feature for c#, but can't seem to find it anywhere.

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/discriminated-unions.md

Answer (score 0):

Found it! That metasyntax belongs to Antlr.

https://www.antlr2.org/doc/metalang.html